# Creating a Table object and appending it later

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

You know how in the normal web DOM, you can create an HTML element, then later add it to the DOM?

I want to do the equivalent of that in Google Apps Script, particularly for Google Docs.  That is, I want to create `Table` object, let's call it `table`, without using `Body.appendTable()`.  Then later I want to append it with `Body.appendTable(table)`--which *does* exist in their API already.

The problem is, I don't see any method like `createTable()` anywhere for this.

### What I've Tried

Simply using `new` doesn't work either, apparently:

```
var table = new Table();
var table = new Document.Table();
var table = new GoogleAppsScript.Document.Table();
```

The respective results are:

```
ReferenceError: "Table" is not defined.
ReferenceError: "Document" is not defined.
ReferenceError: "GoogleAppsScript" is not defined.
```

(I tried the last one based on https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.document.d.ts .)

Or maybe it would work, if I knew the path to the `Table` interface.  It's not this either, though:

```
var table = new DocumentApp.Document.Table();
```

...because that yields:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "Table" from undefined.
```

(Which makes sense.  `DocumentApp` doesn't have a `Document` key.)

### Motivation:

I know that I could create a temporary doc, then add a temporary table to it, and delete it afterwards.

But that means anywhere the script might die, the user will have to manually clean up this temporary doc themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2D array `var table =[[]]`. Then modify it as you wish. [`Body.appendTable(array)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendTable(String)) accepts a string array.

Alternatively, [`Body.appendTable()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendTable()) returns a table object, which you can modify/move later.

Comment: That still appends a table first.  So does my answer, but at least in mine it's invisible.  ;)

Comment: Actually I guess your "Alternatively" covers that in a sense, but doesn't address the `without using Body.appendTable()` requirement of the OP.  But I just finished a more complete answer as your post appeared--the key is that you can immediately remove the invisible table and it still works.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kev, I'm saying use array as a table>do what you want with the array> then append the array as table.

Comment: Yes, but I was already aware of `Body.appendTable()`--given that I had said I was trying to avoid using it to create the table!  Both `Body.appendTable()` and `Body.appendTable(array)` will create a table in-place, but I was trying to create a table _without appending_.  Since there doesn't seem to be a way to do that after all, the closest you can get is appending and immediately removing, which retains a valid reference to a `Table` object that you can still append later.

Comment: Even that had a flaw though--the solution was to use `insertTable(0)` and immediately remove it--see edits to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily add an empty table, then remove it, and the reference is still good and can be used to append later:

```
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var table = body.insertTable(0);
  body.removeChild(table);
  // ...
  table.appendTableRow().appendTableCell('test');
  // ...
  body.appendTable(table);
```

In particular, this addresses the issue of not having anything to clean up if the script dies in either of the `// ...` parts.

Also, initially using `appendTable()` or any of its variants instead of `insertTable(0)` means that Google Docs will automatically append a blank paragraph as well.  Unfortunately, trying to remove it causes the error, `Google Apps Script: Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section.`

So using `insertTable(0)` ensures that there is absolutely no change to the original document until/unless you decide to `appendTable(table)` later, i.e. nothing whatsoever to clean up if the script fails before that point.